# how to use two different OnClickListener in same activity?

Tags: java, android

I need to import following two different library

```
import android.content.DialogInterface.OnClickListener;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
```

as I want both `DialogInterface.OnClickListener` and `View.OnClickListener` in the same activity!!

how can I handle this?!!

because when I use both `onClickListener` I got an error!

Is it possible to have two different `onClickListener` in one class?!!

Answer (score 2):

Import just `android.content.DialogInterface` and `android.view.View`. Then you'll be able to reference the different OnClickListener classes by qualifying them with the parent class, as in

```
DialogInterface.OnClickListener foo = ...;
// and
View.OnClickListener bar = ...;
```

You're lucky, in this case, because the two classes with the same name happen to be nested classes. If they weren't - the only difference being the package name, you'd have to use the fully-qualified class name of at least one of them:

```
android.content.DialogInterface.OnClickListener foo = ...;
OnClickListener bar = ...;

// or 
OnClickListener foo = ...;
android.view.View.OnClickListener bar = ...;

// or
android.content.DialogInterface.OnClickListener foo = ...;
android.view.View.OnClickListener bar = ...;
```

which is neither fun to read nor write.

Answer (score 1):

one way to go could be

```
 public class MyClass implements DialogInterface.OnClickListener, View.OnClickListener {

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could import one and call the next `onClickListener` as say `Dialog.onClickListener`

Answer (score 0):

Make your class implement the interfaces

```
  extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener,DialogInterface.OnClickListener
```

Then

```
@Override
public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
    // do something

}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // dosomething
}
```